# C# exporting e-mails to excel on widndows forms using microsoft.office.interop.excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop, export-to-excel, mailto

I need to export some data to excel in my forms aplication, so i used microsoft.office.interop.excel and everything is ok except one thing. 
When exporting client's email I would like to make it an mailto: link.

```
excellApp.Cells[row, 16] = "mailto:"+client.Email;
```

doesn't work

When I add hiperlink when exporting www field it looks like this:

> excelWorkSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(excellApp.Cells[row,
>   14],
>   client.Www, Type.Missing,
>   Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

How can I export an email to have similar effect coz right now I have only simple fields without any action...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
excelWorkSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(excellApp.Cells[row, 14], "mailto:youremail@test.com", Type.Missing, "Someones Mail", Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it works only in a half coz i get the hyperlink to the email client in excel, but the field has the "mailto:" text also...

Comment: ok it worked in next line I just did:

((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excellApp.Cells[row, 16]).Value2 = client.Email;

and it remembered from the previous line that this was an mailto field ;)